# How can I query the number of physical cores from MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, operating-system, multicore, hyperthreading

Does anyone know of a way to query the number of physical cores from MATLAB? I would specifically like to get the number of physical rather than logical cores (which can differ when hyperthreading is enabled).

I need the method to be cross-platform (Windows and Linux, don't care about Mac), but I'd be happy to use two separate methods with a `switch` statement based on the output of `computer`.

So far I've tried:

1. `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors`
2. `System.Environment.ProcessorCount`
3. `!wmic cpu get NumberOfCores` and `!wmic cpu get NumberOfLogicalProcessors`.

1 is cross-platform, but returns the number of logical rather than physical processors.

2 is Windows only, and also returns logical rather than physical processors.

3 gives both physical and logical processors, but is also Windows only, and although I can use it successfully from the DOS command window, for some reason it seems to hang for an eternity when run from MATLAB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the undocumented command

```
feature('numcores')
```

as explained here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function/

Comment: Ah - there's a bit of undocumented secret sauce, perfect. Thanks @Edric. Do you have any idea why the system call to `wmic` might have been hanging? There are lots of other things that could be useful for if it worked.

Comment: Hmm, dunno, `wmic` "works for me". Maybe add `< nul` to the end of the command?

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')
```

Comment: oh, I haven't try and I don't know. :)

Comment: This stopped working on my machine now. I think the answer above this one is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `maxNumCompThreads`. However it's deprecated. Still it works on Matlab 2011a.

```
maxNumCompThreads
Warning: maxNumCompThreads will be removed in a future release. Please remove any
instances of this function from your code. 
> In maxNumCompThreads at 27

ans =

     4
```