# Determine the Maximum Number of Processors Available for matlabpool (MATLAB Parallel Toolbox)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I'm currently writing some code in MATLAB that uses the `parfor` loop  to speed up some tedious calculations.

My issue is that the code will be run on a remote cluster, and could be run on 4-core, 8-core or 12-core machines (I won't know which one in advance)...

I basically need a code snippet that will allow MATLAB to determine the maximum number of cores that can be used in matlabpool. If we call this variable `maxcores`, I can then go ahead and use

`matlabpool('open',maxcores)`.

so that I can make sure that I am using all the cores that are available to me.

Comment: An alternative approach to Dougal's would be to use a system call. On Linux that'd be `[~, Result] = system('nproc')`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I query the number of physical cores from MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311426/how-can-i-query-the-number-of-physical-cores-from-matlab)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the number of cores on the machine through `feature('numCores')`, which is undocumented but seems unlikely to break. ([source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154551))

Someone claims there that `getNumberOfComputationalThreads` also works since R2007a, but it doesn't on my R2012a.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond Dougal's response, I found `getenv('NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS')` returns the number of threads on my Windows systems.

Comment: This alternative seems more useful compared to feature('numCores') since it returns the number of logical cores, rather than physical.

Comment: Not available in Mac with Matlab 2015a.