# Does parpool ever terminate processes on a worker/core when it is opened?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have the same issue as the OP of this post: [Determine the Maximum Number of Processors Available for matlabpool (MATLAB Parallel Toolbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215812/determine-the-maximum-number-of-processors-available-for-matlabpool-matlab-para/13215850#13215850).  I am considering using feature('numCores') to solve the problem, but I am worried that doing so may actually kick other people's work from cores that are being used. Any thoughts? Has anyone here ever seen Matlab's parpool kick off other work being processed on a core?  I've read the basic documentation on this feature, and haven't been able to find anything related to this topic.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, if cores are not available (being used), they wont be used, but not an expert....

Comment: Can you explain what it is you want to do? Also, what scheduler are you using? You should use the NumWorkers property of the cluster rather than feature('numcores'), because it is the number of available MATLAB workers that is important for determining the size of the pool not the number of cores on the machine (these may or may not be the same depending on the cluster configuration).